# Hibernate generating duplicate UUIDs

Tags: java, linux, hibernate

We have a 6 node Red Hat 4.4.7 / Linux 2.6.32 network, each node running a Java application that creates records in a central Oracle database using Hibernate 3.3.2.GA.

We have run into an issue where Hibernate generates duplicate UUIDs.

The Java class in question is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "X_Y")
@GenericGenerator(name = "x-y-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
public class XY implements ... {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "X_Y_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "x-y-uuid")
    private String id;
    ...
}
```

Using this definition, which we have been using successfully for a while, we ran into problems of duplicate X_Y_ID keys. We disabled the the unique constraint on X_Y_ID  and reran the process. In the meanwhile, we started digging around for possible errors in our code as well as in the Hibernate code. Reading Hibernate's `UUIDHexGenerator` it would appear that UUID's first 8 characters are based on the machine IP address, and the second 8 characters are based JVM start time.

After the process with the disabled unique constraint on X_Y_ID completed, we did some analysis of the resulting UUIDs. We found that there were in fact 59 duplicate X_Y_ID values. 
To our amazement, the query:

```
select SUBSTR(X_Y_ID,1,8), COUNT(*)
from X_Y
group by SUBSTR(X_Y_ID,1,8)
```

indicated that all 6 machines have the same first 8 characters. The query:

```
select SUBSTR(X_Y_ID,9,8), COUNT(*)
from X_Y
group by SUBSTR(X_Y_ID,9,8)
```

gave

```
"49d99de6"  2148309
"49d99e3c"  2044966
"49d99def"  2228095
"49d99df2"  2091068
"49d99dee"  4110661
```

As you can see there are 5 rows with the last having approximately twice the number of rows. This in itself it not surprising. (All it means it that the JVM's on two different machines started up within 256ms of each other).

A little further investigation, showed that the value generated for the first eight characters, `ff808081`, corresponds to the IP address of 127.0.0.1, the localhost.

Running `ifconfig` on one of these machines gives (as an example):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:81:2C:20  
          inet addr:10.191.8.50  Bcast:10.191.63.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe81:2c20/64 Scope:Link
          ...

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          ...
```

My questions are:

- How is it possible that the IP address seen by Hibernate is 127.0.0.1 and not say 10.191.8.50?
- What can we do to prevent this on a deployed system?

Comment: This is clearly a bug in Hibernate that should be fixed on their side. However, `grep $HOSTNAME /etc/hosts` and see if you have an entry `127.0.0.1 yourhostname`

Comment: @JasonC Why is it not a bug that Hibernate is generating UUIDs that are not universal nor unique? If they had followed the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) instead of rolling their own, this would not have happened.

Comment: @thatotherguy Yeah, actually, looking at `UUIDHexGenerator` a bit more closely, it's a pretty poor implementation. I never really appreciated how off it was... I'm going to rework my answer below a bit to reflect this.

Comment: @JasonC, @thatotherguy, we had a look at the /etc/hosts. It has a mapping of `127.0.0.1` to `thehostname`, as well as a mapping of `10.191.8.50` to `thehostname`. According to this http://serverfault.com/questions/584443/should-etc-hosts-contain-an-entry-like-127-0-0-1-localhost-myhost-example-org it is "frowned upon". I will have to see what can be done.

Comment: @AndrewStein Ensuring a correct mapping of your host name to the LAN IP is probably the easiest thing to do. In the long run, you probably want to use a custom generator that generates proper UUIDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @thatotherguy points out in comments, the Hibernate implementation of `AbstractUUIDGenerator` and `UUIDHexGenerator` is pretty far away from being RFC-4122 compliant. I had never really realized how poor the implementation was until I took a closer look.

That aside, taking its implementation for what it is, the root cause of your issue here boils down to [`UUIDHexGenerator`s](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/id/UUIDHexGenerator.java) use of [`InetAddress.getLocalHost()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost()) (via `AbstractUUIDGenerator`) to come up with a "unique" value. If a name lookup for your host name results in 127.0.0.1 (e.g. its in your `/etc/hosts` file), or if the host name is "local", this is what it will use.

You have a few options:

1. You could update `/etc/hosts` to contain the LAN IP for your host name, if this is an option. Still, you will not be using proper UUIDs (same caveat as last part of the next point).
2. If Hibernate's algorithm is insufficient, you can define a custom [`IdentifierGenerator`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/id/IdentifierGenerator.html) and provide a better UUID generation algorithm more suitable for your task. I would base this off of Java's built-in [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), which is compliant. However, you could *probably* "hack" it by extending [`UUIDHexGenerator`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/id/UUIDHexGenerator.html) and overriding `protected int getIP()` to return an accurate IP address. This is a hack because of [`AbstractUUIDGenerator`s implementation](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/id/AbstractUUIDGenerator.java) (your `getIP()` would no longer return the value of its `IP` instance field) and because it still wouldn't be a proper UUID. It may be sufficient but I do not recommend it.
3. Instead of using a generator, specify manual ID assignment, and generate the UUIDs yourself. Again, Java's `UUID` can work for you here.
4. There is a newer UUID generator strategy, "uuid2", which uses [`UUIDGenerator`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/UUIDGenerator.html). It was new in 3.6, not available in 3.3.2. The source for it [is available](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/id/UUIDGenerator.java). I have not used this strategy before and cannot speak for it; however, as Andrew Stein observed in the comments below, an inspection of the source shows that it [provides a strategy built around Java's `UUID`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/id/uuid/StandardRandomStrategy.java), making it likely to be a good bet, and certainly better than the older `AbstractUUIDGenerator`-derived variants.

Option 1 is the simplest quick fix if it works for you, but could have maintenance / deployment issues and, again, doesn't really generate well-formed UUIDs. In the long run, option 2 using `UUID` (or option 4 with the appropriate strategy) is probably the most correct.

There is an [article describing various UUID assignment strategies for Hibernate](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers), which may contain some more helpful insights and examples.

Comment: Hi @JasonC, thank you very much for your suggestion. A point of interest is that the default `UUIDGenerator` used by "uuid2" infact boils down to Java's UUID, as can be seen in the source code here: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/id/uuid/StandardRandomStrategy.java

Comment: @AndrewStein Ah, good to know. It was the right thing for them to do, I'm glad they went that route.